# Java Security overriding whitelist

Tags: firefox, java, security

I'm running 15.04 on a custom build and Java Security is giving me fits.  I need to run apps from a specific site that keep throwing a security error.  No problem, I go into the control panel and whitelist that domain.  I also add the specific app URLs to the whitelist.  Nope.  Whenever I launch the page / app I get a popup from Java Security saying that it has blocked the app from loading.  However, when I click OK on that and then right click the page itself and pull up permissions, Java is set to Allow.  So that's where I'm stuck.  The URLs appear in the whitelist of my control panel.  The pageinfo says Java is allowing the app, but every time I open the page I get the popup that Java Security has blocked it and the app never loads.